# Removing backslash and newline character within one column

Tags: java, groovy

I'm getting text string html along with backslash and newline character. I can easily remove html tags using `.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","")` but still \ and new line character still exists. So, again i tried to `replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n","")` but removing end of line characters.

Input String:

```
test1|test2|test3|test4|test5
testa|testB|testc|testd|teste
test11|test22|
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="master_tbl">\
<tbody>\
<tr id="master_cr">\
<td>\
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s3801_tbl">\
<tbody>\
<tr id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s3801_cr">\
<td>\
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s3801_ctl03" width="100%">\
<tbody>\
<tr>\
<td><span id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s3801_f25914c">test33</span></td>\
</tr>\
</tbody>\
</table>\
</td>\
</tr>\
</tbody>\
</table>\
</td>\
</tr>\
</tbody>\
</table>|test44|test55
test66|test77|test88|test99|test00
```

Expected output string:

```
test1|test2|test3|test4|test5
testa|testB|testc|testd|teste
test11|test22|test33|test44|test55
test66|test77|test88|test99|test00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a strange request and i'd fix it in place where you are generating input text

however seems each new-line that you want to remove prepended with a backslash `\`

```
input.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","")
     .replaceAll("\\\\[\\r\\n]+","") // backslach+newline -> empty
     .replaceAll("\\|[\\r\\n]+","|") // pipe+newline -> pipe
```